# Adding Combox in C# DataGridView (Winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms, csv, datagridview, combobox

I have few DataGrids in my form, and my data source is CSV Files in which I already set the columns to show. In short, when I select New Project, CSV Files is loaded from default location and shows a grid with empty rows and column names.
Now what I want to do is add a dropdownlist (combo box) control for Column 1, which in case of empty grid, remain empty, and in case of CSV file with Data, shows the data dynamically, but I am clueless how to do it. I never added a combobox in grid. All the examples, inlcuding MSDN are more than confusing.
I am newbie and clear answers are more than welcome.
Here is the code, how I am loading CSV Data

```
string[] strColumns = null;
string[] strData = null;

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(strCSV);
DataTable dt = null;
int RowCount = 0;

while (!sr.EndOfStream)
{
    String strRow = sr.ReadLine().Trim();
    if (strRow.Length > 0)
    {
        strData = strRow.Split(delimter);

        if (RowCount == 0)
        {
            RowCount = 1;
            strColumns = strRow.Split(delimter);
            dt = new DataTable();

            foreach (string csvcolumn in strColumns)
            {
                DataColumn column = new DataColumn(csvcolumn.ToUpper(), typeof(string));
                column.DefaultValue = string.Empty;
                dt.Columns.Add(column);
            }
        }

        else
        {
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            for (int i = 0; i < strColumns.Length; i++)
            {
                row[strColumns[i]] = strData[i] == null ? string.Empty : strData[i].ToString();
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }
}
sr.Close();
sr.Dispose();
return dt;
```

Comment: it's not clear to me what you want to achieve. do you want o add `DataGridViewComboBoxColumns` or a `ComboBox` (outside the DataGridView)?

Comment: @stefankmitph i want to add DataGridViewComboBoxCell , where ColumnIndex == 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
             DataGridViewComboBoxCell comboJob = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();

            //these data will be displayed in comboBox:

            string[] data = JobIdList.ToArray();

            comboJob.Items.AddRange(data);

            this.dgInfo()[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex] = comboJob;

            bValidating = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3;
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Product ID";
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Product Name";
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Product Price";

        string[] row = new string[] { "1", "Product 1", "1000" };
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
        row = new string[] { "2", "Product 2", "2000" };
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
        row = new string[] { "3", "Product 3", "3000" };
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
        row = new string[] { "4", "Product 4", "4000" };
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);

        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cmb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        cmb.HeaderText = "Select Data";
        cmb.Name = "cmb";
        cmb.MaxDropDownItems = 4;
        cmb.Items.Add("True");
        cmb.Items.Add("False");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(cmb);

    }
}
```

Comment: i think the code is pretty comprehensive. But i take note !

Comment: i already have defined columns, which i already loaded from Blank CSV File and there may be data in Rows (in case of old project) and there may be not in case of new project. what i need is, add dropdown in cells of those already defined columns.